# Raising and Handling events in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to increment the value on Items component on a button click which is handled by its child component Item. Items have an array of key-value pairs and this value needs to increment and render it
Here is the code

```
//parent component
class Items extends React.Component{
  state={
    items:[{ id: 1, value: 9 }, 
           { id: 2, value: 10 }, 
           { id: 3, value: 0 }]
  }
  
  handleIncrement=()=>{
   
  //need to increment items.value on each button click increment. How can I access it
    
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Increment item on the list From Parent</h2>
        {this.state.items.map(item=>(<Item key={item.id}
          value={item.value} id={item.id} onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
        />))}
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}


//child component
class Item extends React.Component{

  getValue=()=>{
    let {value}=this.props;
    return value===0?'Zero':value
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>{this.getValue()}</span>
        <button  onClick={this.props.onIncrement}>Increment</button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

please help me with this.

Comment: have you tried using `setState`? [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

Comment: no, i have doubt on accessing the id of each value.because the event is handled by another component so we need to pass the id right?

Answer (score 0):

You might add `id` as button name

```
<button name={this.props.id} onClick={this.props.onIncrement}>Increment</button>
```

and then use it at your function

```
 handleIncrement= e =>   
   this.setState({ items: this.state.items.map(item =>
              item.id == e.target.name ? {...item, value: item.value++ } : item ) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can update by array index instead of object id

```
//parent component
class Items extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ id: 1, value: 9 }, { id: 2, value: 10 }, { id: 3, value: 0 }]
  };

  handleIncrement = e => {
    //need to increment items.value on each button click increment.How can i access it
    const id = e.target.id;
    const tempItems = this.state.items;
    tempItems[id] = {...tempItems[id], value: ++tempItems[id].value}
    this.setState((prevState)=>({ items: tempItems}));

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Increment item on the list From Parent</h2>
        {this.state.items.map((item,i) => (
          <Item
            key={item.id}
            value={item.value}
            id={item.id}
            index={i}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//child component
class Item extends React.Component {
  getValue = () => {
    let { value } = this.props;
    return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.getValue()}</span>
        <button id={this.props.index} onClick={this.props.onIncrement}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
  items: [{ id: 1, value: 9 }, { id: 2, value: 10 }, { id: 3, value: 0 }]
};

handleIncrement = id => event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const s = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.items)); // dereference
    const ndx = s.map(e => e.id).indexOf(id);
    s[ndx]["value"]++;
    this.setState({ items: s });
  };
```

here's a sandbox you can preview with the implementation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-voice-kkq7b?file=/src/Increment.js:380-803